# C++ interface returns a reference - is it a bad practice?

Tags: c++, interface

I'm trying to implement several caching algorithms, where one can replace another in runtime.

So I've started with describing an interface:

```
class ICache
{
  public:
    virtual ~ICache(){}
    virtual const std::vector<SomeValue>& getSomeValues() const = 0;
    virtual const std::vector<AnotherValue>& getAnotherValues() const = 0;
    ...
}
```

And here comes my question - is it a bad practice to return a reference in interface?

Such design enforce and exposure an internal implementation of class, which implements it (as it "has to" store all vectors as members).

Is there a better way?

Comment: The class could itself store only references or fetch them on demand from some other place.

Comment: It's a good habbit, there is nothing wrong with returning const references, it's efficient.

Comment: As lpng as you make sure, your cache class outlives any external references to those values, this is perfectly fine. However, if you want to switch the caching class during runtime, this migjt nit allways be the case. Assuming of course your Cache classes destry the cached objects at the end of their lifetime. What kind of objects are you planning to cache?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any difficulty with returning references in this context. The interface is just a contract between the caller and the service. I agree that the nature of this contract seems to imply that it is better on the cache side to store the data internally this way but doesn't force the implementation to do so; and from an implementation point of view it allows a mechanism which can be very efficient when used correctly (as opposed to forcing the creation of a new vector and passing it by value).